# Ordenar pelo resultado da soma de dois SUM - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Preciso ordenar uma consulta pelo resultado da soma de duas somas.

```
ORDER BY SUM(SUM() + SUM())
```

Tentei o seguinte:

```
SELECT 
   SUM(campo1 + campo2)   AS soma1
   , SUM(campo3 + campo4) AS soma2
   , SUM(soma1 + soma2)   AS ordenacao
WHERE 
   condicoes_where 
ORDER BY 
   ordenacao 
DESC
```

A query é essa:

```
SELECT 

SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( x.tempo_total_atendimento ) ) + SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( x.tempo_chat ) ) ) AS ordenacao

FROM (
        SELECT

            case when SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( a.duracao ) ) + SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( t.at_duracao ) ) ) is null then 
                SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( a.duracao ) ) )
            else
                SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( a.duracao ) ) + SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( t.at_duracao ) ) )
            end AS tempo_total_atendimento,

            SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( TIMEDIFF(c.con_data_fim, DATE_FORMAT(c.con_data, '%H:%i:%s')) ) ) ) AS tempo_chat

            FROM atendimentos AS a 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN atendimentos_texto AS t ON t.atendimento = a.id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN chat_conversa AS c ON c.con_file = a.chat

            WHERE a.data_inicio BETWEEN '2017-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-09-26 23:59:59'

            GROUP BY a.cliente
        ) x
```

**Prints dos resultados**

[image: Resultado dos antes da pergunda]

[image: Resultado da resposta do @Sorack]

Comment: Alguma das resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de escolher uma e marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer ordenação de somatórios você não precisa criar subqueries não.
Consultas assim, funcionam bem:

```
select ID, SUM(QUANTIDADE_A), SUM(QUANTIDADE_B), SUM(QUANTIDADE_A + QUANTIDADE_B) AS TOTAL
from pedidos_itens
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY TOTAL DESC
```

Tem uma sintaxe no teu SQL que eu não faria de jeito nenhum.

```
SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( a.duracao ) ) + SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( t.at_duracao ) ) )
```

Talvez por isso você tenha resultados estranhos. Eu trocaria por algo mais semântico:

```
 SEC_TO_TIME( SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(a.duracao) + TIME_TO_SEC(t.at_duracao)) )
```

Além de garantir resultados esperados, teu código fica mais clean e fácil de entender.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode chegar ao fim desejado utilizando uma `suquery` e referenciando a posição da coluna no `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT x.atendimento_duracao + x.texto_duracao + chat_duracao AS total_duracao
  FROM (SELECT SUM(COALESCE(TIME_TO_SEC(a.duracao), 0)) atendimento_duracao,
               SUM(COALESCE(TIME_TO_SEC(at.at_duracao), 0)) texto_duracao,
               SUM(COALESCE(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(c.con_data_fim, DATE_FORMAT(c.con_data, '%H:%i:%s'))), 0)) chat_duracao
          FROM atendimentos a
               LEFT JOIN atendimentos_texto at ON at.atendimento = a.id
               LEFT JOIN chat_conversa cc ON cc.con_file = a.chat
         WHERE a.data_inicio BETWEEN '2017-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-09-26 23:59:59'
         GROUP BY a.cliente) x
 ORDER BY 1
```

Nesta `query` cada uma das durações está sendo somada, e caso esteja `NULL` na tabela, será considerado como zero, assim a somatória total não será afetada. Após isso será ordenada pela coluna de posição 1 (Considerando o `ORDER BY 1`).

Comment: valeu pela resposta (e tão rápido) quase deu certo, pra ti entender meu problema, preciso trazer a soma de tempo de está em três tabelas (tabela1 + tabela2) e tabela3, preciso somar tudo e ordenar pelo soma do tempo que são atendimento em um helpdesk.

Comment: @AlexandreVieira é melhor você fornecer o nome das colunas e conteúdos na sua pergunta, assim posso montar uma `query` voltada para a sua especificação

Comment: Editei a pergunta vê se ajuda.

Comment: @AlexandreVieira alterei. Verifique por favor.

Comment: O resulta ainda não é o esperado, anexei dois prints com os resultados antes e depois da edição, note que o que preciso é a soma das tempo_total_atendimento e tempo_chat. Obrigado.

Comment: @AlexandreVieira essa sua coluna é `TIME` mesmo?

Comment: não, na verdade duas são char e 1 é time

Comment: @AlexandreVieira então, tem que ver porque não dá pra entender se seu formato é `HH:mm:ss`. Fora que aparentemente você não quer só ordenar, você quer mostrar algum dado extra

Comment: pois é, esse banco eu peguei assim, só estou fazendo um relatório e preciso ordenar por essa soma, mas vou deixar assim mesmo, vou partir para a ordenação pelo php mesmo, talvez de certo. Valeu.